# parse string value to an Object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, swift, express

Hi then I have a problem like this: I have an application written in swift that sends values ​​with a *json* array to *node.js*! Should I extrapolate the Username and Password parameters? how can I do?

**Swift Code:**

```
// prepare json data
let json: [String: Any] = ["Username": ""+UsernameTextBox.text!,"Password": ""+PasswordTextBox.text!]

let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

// create post request
let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/login")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

// insert json data to the request
request.httpBody = jsonData

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
        return
    }
    let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
        print(responseJSON)
    }
}

task.resume()
```

**Node.js Code:**

```
var express = require("express");
var myParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();

//Login 
app.use(myParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
   app.post("/login", function(request, response) {
     console.log(request.body); 

    });

//Application Listen on Port
app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Application Server Start on Port: 3000");
})
```

**Log of Body:**

[image]

**New JavaScript Code Image:**

[image]

Comment: Not really an expert in swift, but you should probably fix the swift request, rather than trying to extract the data within the server

Comment: The request body should look like `{"username":"blah", password:"blahblah"}`

Comment: @Malice For work reasons I am forced to use this mode to proceed! However, the same swift code I have used several times with php and I have never had problems, but at the moment I am forced to use node.js and I do not know how to solve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why using `JSON.stringify` on a string, remove it and your code should work:

```
var data = JSON.parse(Object.keys(request.body)[0]);
var username = data.Username;
var password = data.Password;
```

```js
var body = {'{"Password":"dsdsd","Username":"dsdsdsds"}':''};

var data = JSON.parse(Object.keys(body)[0]);
var username = data.Username;
var password = data.Password;

console.log(username, password);
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of :

```
console.log(request.body);
```

is

```
{{"username": "something", "password": "somethingElse"}: ""}
```

You can change the form of the data to something you can easily access like this one :

```
{"Username": "something", "Password": "somethingElse"}
```

But, if for some reasons, you prefer to stick to the way the data is sent in your question,  you can extract your user credentials with:

```
 var data = JSON.parse(Object.keys(request.body)[0]);
 var username = data.Username;
 var password = data.Password;
```

Comment: I tried with the code you told me but I print this error: TypeError: Object.key is not a function ......

Comment: It's Object.keys

Comment: I replaced the key with the keys, 
but when I print the username and password values ​​it tells me: undefined

Comment: You will need to JSON.parse(data), No ?

Comment: @edkeveked
then I tried to use the new code but keep writing me undefined!

Comment: it's Username and Password

Comment: `U` and `P` capitals

Comment: Pushpendra's answer is also worth a try

Comment: I added an image above

Comment: @RiccardoPirani, now you have a working snippet to show what to do

Answer (score 1):

Change extended to false and try this one and you will get json object in request body.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Answer (score 1):

To extend to @edkeveked,

```
var data = JSON.parse(Object.keys(request.body)[0]);
var username = data.Username;
var password = data.Password;
```

Comment: I had already tried this type of solution but he always writes me undefined

Comment: could you try printing data

Comment: if i print data, i have: {"Password":"orere","Username":"prov"}

Comment: Looks like you have quotes in the key, You will need to retrieve it using `data['"Password"']` or something

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162110/discussion-between-malice-and-riccardo-pirani).